# exclude array doesn't work in PHP

Tags: php

below is my code through which I'm trying get certain values to a drop down box from a SQL database. I'm also trying to exclude some of the data before loading to the dropdown box.

In my code `$excld[]` works fine and the expected zero values are not shown when the dropdown is populated, but the values I expect to exclude via `$exclude=$rec['chkNum'];` doesn't work, or else the values I dont want to be in the dropdown still shows. Can someone tell me is there anything wrong in the approach?
thanks.

```
$exclude = array();
$query = "SELECT * FROM invoentry WHERE dist_inv='$distUsr'";
$runx=mysqli_query($db,$query) or die ("SQL Error");
$norx=mysqli_num_rows($runx);

while ($rec = mysqli_fetch_array($runx))
{
    $exclude[] = $rec['chkNum']; $excld[] = '0';
}

$SQLx="SELECT * FROM newchk WHERE dist_chk='$distUsr'";
$runx=mysqli_query($db,$SQLx) or die ("SQL Error");
$norx=mysqli_num_rows($runx);

while ($rec = mysqli_fetch_array($runx))
    {
        if($rec['sbstart'] != '0' & $rec['sbend'] != '0') {
        for($i=$rec['sbstart']; $i<=$rec['sbend']; $i++)
        {
            if (!in_array($i, $exclude, $excld))
            {
                echo "<option id='options' value='$i'>$i<br></option>";
            }
        } }

         if($rec['gwstart'] != '0' & $rec['gwend'] != '0') {
        for($i=$rec['gwstart']; $i<=$rec['gwend']; $i++)
        {
            if (!in_array($i, $exclude, $excld))
            {
                echo "<option id='options' value='$i'>$i<br></option>";
            }
        } }
    }
```

**EDIT :**

Database structure is as follows;
Database name :regional_data
Two tables in the same database invoentry and newchk

**invoentry:**

```
usr_inv dist_inv chkNum InvoNum
---------------------------------
John     Guardian   300455   457gXT
```

**newchk:**

```
usr_chk  dist_chk sbstart sbend totsb gwstart gwend totgw
----------------------------------------------------------
John     Guardian 300400  300550 151   300     310   10
```

Comment: Could you edit your question to show us the structure of the `invoentry` and `newchk` tables?  There's probably a pure-SQL solution to this problem.

Comment: @Charles : Hi I tried to update the database table structure with header and a sample data set. Hope this clarifies and please bear with me if the looks isn't that great.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't see how it could work in <del>any case</del> (ok, in first iteration it can work, since `$i` is still string then). Take a look what parameters `in_array` accepts

> bool **in_array** ( mixed *$needle* , array *$haystack* [, bool *$strict* = **FALSE** ] )

In your case, you are passing: integer `$i`, array of strings `$exclude` (everything fetched from database is a string, unless you cast it yourself) and non empty array `$excld` filled with string "0". Last argument evaluates to `TRUE` (array is not empty) so php is checking not only values but also types. Since you ara passing integer and array of strings, php would not find any elements inside with same type and value, so it will print all elements.

What to change to make it work:

```
while ($rec = mysqli_fetch_array($runx))
{
    $exclude[] = $rec['chkNum']; //remove $excld[] = '0';
}
// add 0 to $exclude
$exclude[] = '0';
```

and

```
if (!in_array($i, $exclude)) //remove , $excl
```

Comment: Thank you @dev-null-dweller. What you have highlighted is correct and I guess now i have the correct understanding og how in_array works. Many thanks for the time taken to review this.